# What's wrong with such a Linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I have two tables:

```
Team: teamId, teamName
Player: playerId, teamId, playerName
```

I want to get the teamName through playerName. I wrote two querys, one of them doesn't work.

```
var query = from t in dc.Teams 
            where t.teamId == ((from p in dc.Players 
                                where p.playerName == "kobe" 
                                select p.teamId).SingleOrDefault()) 
            select t.teamName;  //Doesn't work

var query = from t in dc.Teams 
            join p in dc.Players 
                on t.teamId equals p.teamId 
            where p.playerName == "kobe" 
            select t.teamName;  //Works
```

Anyone can tell me why the first query couldn't work?

Comment: You should have known by now how to indent code...

Comment: Error message? It seems your are trying to do a projection (select) after the call to SingleOrDefault(). That makes no sense.

Comment: Do you get an error, or is it just not returning what you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both queries should yield the same result if there are one or zero players named "kobe".  If there are more than one players named "kobe", the first query won't return anything because its subquery uses `SingleOrDefault`, which returns the default value if the collection doesn't contain exactly one value, while the second query will return the teamName for each player named "kobe".

Answer (score 1):

Risky Martin already mentioned the reasons but in addition to this, 
You can use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `SingleOrDefault`. By using `FirstOrDefault`, your query can return any amount of results but you state that you only want the first result.

```
var query = from t in dc.Teams 
            where t.teamId == ((from p in dc.Players 
                                where p.playerName == "kobe" 
                                select p.teamId).FirstOrDefault()) 
            select t.teamName;  //Now it works
```